# How do you render 2 or more DataSets with .net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 DataSets that I would like to render in a view. I have seen several examples to render one, but not two.

It is possible to put the DataSets in the ViewData Collection but then they are not "DataSets" any more when accessing them in the veiw.

Thanks.

Comment: You can cast them to DataSets in the View

Comment: ViewData is nasty. Using a ViewModel means everything is strongly typed and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewData is a bit hacky and easily abused.

You should create a ViewModel and place them there.
Fill the Model in the Controller, then pass it to the View.

**MODEL**

```
public class MyPageModel
{
    public DataSet data1 { get; set; }
    public DataSet data2 { get; set; }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/whatever.master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyNamespace.MyPageModel>" %>

<%: foreach (var row in Model.data1.Tables[0].Rows) { blah blah blah } %>
<%: foreach (var row in Model.data2.Tables[0].Rows) { blah blah blah } %>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult MyPage()
{
    var model = new MyPageModel();

    // Fill model.data1 here....
    // Fill model.data2 here....

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: if you have n number of datasets, use a property of type List<DataSet> or a Dictionary<string, DataSet>, instead of data1 and data2